# Working with Resources in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridview, resources, styles

I am wanting to use the example from

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2008/09/22/lt-howto-gt-replace-listview-columns-with-rows-lt-howto-gt.aspx

However I don't want to put this into the App.xaml code as this will apply to ALL gridviews, how do I apply this example to a select few gridviews in the application? The Resources look like this

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                      Focusable="false">
                                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                                        Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Minimum="0.0"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=OneWay}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Cursor="Arrow"/>
                        <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Vertical"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Minimum="0.0"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=OneWay}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                               Cursor="Arrow"/>
                        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Background="{Binding Path=Background,ElementName=PART_VerticalScrollBar}"
                               LastChildFill="false">
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                   Width="1"
                                   Fill="White"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                            <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                   Height="1"
                                   Fill="White"
                                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewHeaderRowPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewRowPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.4091"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F8F9" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFF2F2F2" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD5D5D5" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFBDEDFF" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFB7E7FB" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8DD6F7" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8AD1F5" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Right" Value="-9"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderBorderBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition MaxHeight="7"/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FFE3F7FF" x:Name="UpperHighlight" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                <Border Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,1" x:Name="HeaderContent" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True">
                                        <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Margin="1,1,0,0" x:Name="HeaderHoverBorder" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"/>
                        <Border Margin="1,0,0,1" x:Name="HeaderPressBorder" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"/>
                        <Canvas>
                            <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderHoverBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF88CBEB"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_HeaderGripper" Value="Transparent"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderPressBackground}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderHoverBorder" Value="#FF95DAF9"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="HeaderPressBorder" Value="#FF7A9EB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="UpperHighlight" Value="#FFBCE4F9"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="PART_HeaderGripper" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="HeaderContent" Value="1,1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Floating">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4082"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Canvas x:Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FF000000" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}" Opacity="0.4697"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Padding">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"/>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I have tried creating a usercontrol and sticking that lot in the UserControl.Resources section but it didn't work, I can only get this example to work if i put them into the Application.Resources section which i obviously don't want. Help!! :-)

Comment: Can you post the code (or at least an extract of the code) that failed when trying the UserControl.Resources route.

Comment: It didn't fail as such it just didn't display like it did when the code was in the Application.Resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an error in your code.

I just copied it to use in a test project and got an error:

> StaticResource reference 'GridViewColumnHeaderGripper' was not found.

on:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
```

Comment: Try using the example in the URL, that's where i got it all from, i was just trying to modify it so it wasn't applied to all gridviews

Answer (score 0):

> However I don't want to put this into the App.xaml code as this will apply to ALL gridviews, how do I apply this example to a select few gridviews in the application?

Just change the key of the style to be something other than `GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey`. Choose a custom key, and set the style explicity on controls that need it (using `{StaticResource styleKey}`)

Comment: I don't think it's as easy as that :-( I tried it before but it got messy.

Comment: I think it *is* as easy as that... The way you declare your style, you override the default style, so it will be used implicitly by all ScrollViewers whose default style key is GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey

Comment: Yeah i understand where you're coming from it's just all the other styles in there, i am not sure how to access them within the Gridview. For Example : 

    Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}"
Or  Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewRowPresenter}"